# Passing an object with JQuery link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using socket.io to receive a list of objects. I am then iterating though them to generate links. I need to display this object when a users selects one, but I dont know how to pass the object though the link?

```
socket.on('result', function (result) {

for (var object in result.blue) {
   $('.res_section').append(
        '<a href="#" id="result_object"> ' + result.blue[object].name +'</a>');
         //I need to append result.blue[object];
    }
 });


 $(document).on("click", "#result_object", function(){
          //do something here with object
 });

object = {name: {first: "a_name", second: "second_name"}, age: {type: "number", value: "13"}}
```

Comment: [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: and what is this result.blue[object]? do you need to pass entire object or would only object key be enough?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get .data() to work with the object (it is long multilayered object) - the elements are undefined. I do need to pass the object as it does not exist until passed by socket.on.

Comment: Firstly, are `#result_object` and `result_option` meant to be the same thing? Otherwise I don't see the link between them. Second, you are generating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which is not valid, and will break your delegated `click` selector - consider setting it as a `class` instead.

Comment: Also `.data()` should work, no matter how complex the object you are storing in it is

Comment: I have changed it to a class. If I do data-object=\' '+result.blue[object]+'  \' I get undefined, and the page stops loading if I take the extra quotations out.

Comment: Thanks, I had to turn in into a JSON object and then manually remove the quotes

Answer (score 0):

The object had to be turned into a JSON object and then the quotations replaced with '&#x27'. It can then be used with .data();

```
    data-object=JSON.stringify(object).replace(/\'/g,'&#x27;')
```